# Hibernate & MySQL: When a record is created, a second record is added and is completely null

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm fairly new to spring and hibernate and I'm creating a simple application that has two entity classes that are linked by @OneToMany and @ManyToOne relationships.

```
@Entity
public class ActiveIngredient {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="active")
    private String active;

    @Column(name="potency")
    private double potency;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="manufacturer")
    private Manufacturer manufacturer;
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Manufacturer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int manId;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String manName;

    @Column(name="country")
    private String country;

    @Column(name="city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="phone")
    private String phone;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH}, mappedBy = "manufacturer")
    private List<ActiveIngredient> activeIngredients;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH}, mappedBy = "manufacturer")
    private List<ExcipientIngredient>excipientIngredients;
```

On the front end, a thymeleaf template is used where users can submit the data to create an ingredient and manufacturer. Below is the controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/excipients")
public class ExcipientIngredientController {

    @Autowired
    private ExcipientIngredientService excipientIngredientService;
    @Autowired
    private ManufacturerService manufacturerService;

    @GetMapping("/listExc")
    public String listExcipients(Model model) {
        List<ExcipientIngredient> theExcipient = excipientIngredientService.findAll();
        //add list to the model.
        model.addAttribute("excipient", theExcipient);
        //return the thymeleaf page with this path.
        return "list-excipients";
    }

    @GetMapping("/addExcipientForm")
    public String addForm(Model model){
        //to add a new excipient ingredient, need to create a new object
        ExcipientIngredient excipientIngredient = new ExcipientIngredient();
        Manufacturer manufacturer = new Manufacturer();

        //add to the model
        model.addAttribute("excipientIngredient", excipientIngredient);
        model.addAttribute("manufacturer", manufacturer);

        return "add-excipient-form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/saveExc")
    public String saveExcipients(@ModelAttribute("excipientIngredient") ExcipientIngredient excipientIngredient, @ModelAttribute("manufacturer") Manufacturer manufacturer) {

        // save the Ingredient
        excipientIngredientService.saveOrUpdate(excipientIngredient);
        manufacturerService.saveOrUpdate(manufacturer);

        // use a redirect to prevent duplicate submissions
        return "redirect:/excipients/listExc";
    }
}
```

and this is the implementation for the save/update method.

```
@Override
    public void saveOrUpdate(ExcipientIngredient excipientIngredient) {

        Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

        currentSession.saveOrUpdate(excipientIngredient);
    }
```

Everything works fine when creating an ingredient and being updated into MySQL database, however, when the manufacturer is added to the database, an extra record is created that is completely null:

[MySQL entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXzLJ.png)

I've been trying for a few hours to resolve this issue but have had no luck. Any suggestions or pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Manufacturer` class, you can try removing the `cascade` parameter from the `@OneToMany` annotation.

Here's a good article that you might find useful: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many

Comment: Hi! I apologize for seeing this so late, this was actually the solution. I've accepted the answer, thank you!